# No release available for sfFormtasticPlugin issue in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 doctrine and I'm having a problem. I was going to install the sfFormtasticPlugin into Plugins directory. But when I try to install in the command prompt I got this msg `"No release available for sfFormtasticPlugin"`. I try to find the release of this plugin and even I try to search to google to resolve this but I found nothing. I wish some one could help me to resolve this issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you said about [**this**](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormtasticPlugin) plugin,I think you can install it from svn:

```
cd plugins;
svn co http://svn.symfony-project.com/plugins/sfFormtasticPlugin/trunk/ sfFormtasticPlugin
```